# Too much white space on an image

Tags: html, css, web, responsive

I want to know if you can assist me with this. I have an image that works perfectly with what I want. The size of the vector itself is great. But, it seems like it has some sort of padding at the top and bottom. Is there any way to eliminate it?

I tried with `position: relative;` but it didn't work. Right know the site is super simple. Here is the HTML:

```
            <div class="hero">
            <div class="main-text">
                <h1>La información que<br>necesitabas encontrar</h1>
                <div id="searchdiv">
                    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Busca una pelicula">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="heroimg">
            <img src="assets/movie.svg" alt="movieguy">
            </div>
     </div>
```

And here is the result of the image:

[image: SVG without CSS]

I'm currently learning CSS and HTML so I will gladly accept any help or feedback. Note: I eliminated any sort of CSS applied to the image.

Comment: Consider reducing the amount of code to a [mcve]. For example, is the navigation really needed to demonstrate the problem? The issue appears to be the SVG but we have no further info on that element.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Done I eliminated any sort of unnecessary information.

Comment: What CSS do you have - in particular have you removed the default margin and padding settings on elements? (Including body).

Comment: Yes indeed. At the moment there is no CSS applied to the image at all. I removed the default padding and margin of the HTML file in general but the image is untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in style :

```
img { vertical-align: top }
```

You can use code below if you don't want to modify block mode:

```
img{vertical-align:text-bottom}
```

Or you can use following as Stuart suggests:

```
img{vertical-align:bottom}
```